# Xamarin : Reduce iOS and Android App size

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using native Xamarin to build my iOS and android apps using MVVMCross. 
The Xamarin solution supports multiple iOS and Android application project.
It has PCL for sharing core logic and Shared Library to share views across multiple apps.

**MY ISSUE:** App size is more than 100MB. I want to reduce the app size.
I am using LLVM complier and 
Linker: Link SDK Only

Can anyone think of any set of techniques for iOS and Android to reduce the app size.

Comment: Within your Android APK, what is the total size of the assemblies directory?

Comment: by assembly directories you mean the size of all the projects used in android as in android project size, pcl and shared lib size ?

Comment: If you unzip your `.APK`, you will find an `assemblies` dir in the root folder, what is the total size of that? (compared to the rest of the app)

Comment: AppSize:149mb assemblies: 86mb

Comment: there is an entire section of docs devoted to this topic: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

Comment: and any document for iOS?

Comment: @TheDeveloper You will definitely want to enable `Link all assemblies` vs. your current `Link SDK Only` to strip the unused code from those assembles, and yes there is Xamarin iOS docs concerning the Linker: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker